# Manually decorating function with extend_schema results in RecursionError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I have a `HistoricalModelViewSet` class which is used in all other view sets (`class StuffViewSet(HistoricalModelViewSet)`), it adds couple of `/history` endpoints (DRF thing, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).

Then I'm using `drf-spectacular` to generate a `/swagger` view, and there is a different structure to the `/history` endpoint than the rest of the view set.

So I dynamically decorate the function with `extend_schema` using a serializer set in the child view:

```py
class HistoricalModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.list_history = extend_schema(
      responses={200: self.historical_serializer_class(many=True)},
    )(self.list_history)

    @action(detail=False, methods=["get"], url_path="history", url_name="list-history-list")
    def list_history(self, request):
      serializer = self.historical_serializer_class(history_items, many=True, context=context)
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

This all works fine, can view `/history` for all models.

However when viewing `/swagger` everything works fine couple of times but then after about 5 reloads it errors with:

```bash
myapp-api-1  | 2023-07-31 11:23:16,553 ERROR django.request log 2577 140001382692608 Internal Server Error: /myapp/schema/
myapp-api-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
myapp-api-1  |     response = get_response(request)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
myapp-api-1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
myapp-api-1  |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
myapp-api-1  |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
myapp-api-1  |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
myapp-api-1  |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
myapp-api-1  |     raise exc
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
myapp-api-1  |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/views.py", line 83, in get
myapp-api-1  |     return self._get_schema_response(request)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/views.py", line 91, in _get_schema_response
myapp-api-1  |     data=generator.get_schema(request=request, public=self.serve_public),
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 268, in get_schema
myapp-api-1  |     paths=self.parse(request, public),
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/generators.py", line 239, in parse
myapp-api-1  |     operation = view.schema.get_operation(
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/utils.py", line 422, in get_operation
myapp-api-1  |     return super().get_operation(path, path_regex, path_prefix, method, registry)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/utils.py", line 422, in get_operation
myapp-api-1  |     return super().get_operation(path, path_regex, path_prefix, method, registry)
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/utils.py", line 422, in get_operation
myapp-api-1  |     return super().get_operation(path, path_regex, path_prefix, method, registry)
myapp-api-1  |   [Previous line repeated 482 more times]
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/openapi.py", line 61, in get_operation
myapp-api-1  |     if self.is_excluded():
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/utils.py", line 427, in is_excluded
myapp-api-1  |     return super().is_excluded()
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/utils.py", line 427, in is_excluded
myapp-api-1  |     return super().is_excluded()
myapp-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/drf_spectacular/utils.py", line 427, in is_excluded
myapp-api-1  |     return super().is_excluded()
myapp-api-1  |   [Previous line repeated 437 more times]
myapp-api-1  | RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Errors on the `/schema`, where `drf-spectacular` is generating the Swagger schema.

Why does it work couple of times and then error?

If I comment out the code in `__init__` everything works, but I have the wrong output JSON in `/swagger`.

But why would this method of decorating not work?